# Signing into Office with Puppeteer not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Whenever I try to use Puppeteer to sign into an Office account, it always says to "Enter a valid email address" on the logging in site (and I know the email is valid, I have tested it). I looked through some other questions, and one of them mentioned that they might have login preventions for Puppeteer, Selenium, etc, though I am not sure. I am able to login if I do it manually.

Here's the code that handles all of that:

```
var email = "myemail@outlook.com"

await page.evaluate((em)=>{
    document.querySelector(`[type="email"]`).value = em;
  },email);

  await page.screenshot({
    path:"./email_input.png"
  })

  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  await page.evaluate((em)=>{
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(document.querySelector(`[type="email"]`).value === em){
            document.querySelector(`[type="submit"]`).dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
  },email);

  await page.screenshot({
      path:"./sign_in_email.png"
  })
```

edit to ManuelMB's comment: It was just a check to make sure that the value was actually the email. It still doesn't work without it.

Comment: Why are you using setInterval for (also you are not using the optional parameter delay)? And after first time you clearInterval. If it was really needed for your purpose you should be using setTimeout (That only executes one)

Comment: This is a wild guess since I never used Puppeteer, but could it be that the login page has some event handlers set to validate the email as the user types it into the email input (ie. keyboard typing events), so programmatically setting a value for the email goes unnoticed and the login page can't really validate it? It might still consider the input as blank. Another possibility (not completely unrelated) is that the input element might be there just for pure UI and setting a value programmatically won't trigger the sync to the real, hidden input used by the validating code.